# Java JTextField actionListener not working

Tags: java, actionlistener, jtextfield

I am making a program using JButtons and JTextFields. The ActionListeners work for JButtons, but not for JTextFields.

```
    public class Gui extends JFrame {

private JButton Subject[] = new JButton[8];
private String SubjNames[] = {"Length", "Mass", "Currency", "Temperature", "Time", "Speed", "Data", "Cooking"};
private JButton Length1[] = new JButton[8];
private JButton Length2[] = new JButton[8];
private String LengNames[] = {"inches", "feet", "yards", "miles", "millimeters", "centimeters", "meters", "kilometers"};
private JTextField convertedFrom;
private JTextField amountFrom;
private JTextField convertedTo;
private JTextField amountTo;
private String from;
private String CTo;
private String ATo;
private int SubjectLocX = 40;
private int SubjectLocY = 50;
private int Length1LocX = 40;
private int Length1LocY = 150;
private int Length2LocX = 330;
private int Length2LocY = 150;
private int t = 0;

public Gui (){

    super("Converter");
    setLayout(null);

    System.out.println("yes");

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    Subject[i] = new JButton(SubjNames[i]);
    Subject[i].setLocation(SubjectLocX,SubjectLocY);
    Subject[i].setSize(200,50);
    add(Subject[i]);
    if (i < 3) {
        SubjectLocX = 40;
        SubjectLocY += 100;
    } else if (i == 3) {
        SubjectLocX = 330;
        SubjectLocY = 50;
    } else if (i > 3) {
        SubjectLocY += 100;
        }
    }

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    Subject[i].addActionListener(handler);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    Length1[i] = new JButton(LengNames[i]);
    Length2[i] = new JButton(LengNames[i]);
    }
    convertedFrom = new JTextField(from, 20);
    convertedTo = new JTextField(CTo, 20);
    amountFrom = new JTextField("amount", 20);
    amountFrom.addActionListener(handler);
    amountTo = new JTextField(ATo, 20);

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        Length1[i].addActionListener(handler);
        Length2[i].addActionListener(handler);
        }

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600,500);
    setLocation(400,200);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void Step2() {

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        remove(Subject[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        remove(Length1[i]);
        remove(Length2[i]);
    }
    remove(convertedFrom);
    remove(convertedTo);
    remove(amountFrom);
    remove(amountTo);

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();

    convertedFrom = new JTextField(from, 20);
    convertedFrom.setEditable(false);
    convertedFrom.setLocation(40,50);
    convertedFrom.setSize(200,30);
    add(convertedFrom);

    convertedTo = new JTextField(CTo, 20);
    convertedTo.setEditable(false);
    convertedTo.setLocation(330,50);
    convertedTo.setSize(200,30);
    add(convertedTo);

    amountFrom = new JTextField("amount", 20);
    amountFrom.setLocation(40,100);
    amountFrom.setSize(200,30);
    add(amountFrom);

    amountTo = new JTextField(ATo, 20);
    amountTo.setEditable(false);
    amountTo.setLocation(330,100);
    amountTo.setSize(200,30);
    add(amountTo);

    Length1LocX = 40;
    Length1LocY = 150;
    Length2LocX = 330;
    Length2LocY = 150;

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        Length1[i].setLocation(Length1LocX, Length1LocY);
        Length1[i].setSize(90, 50);
        add(Length1[i]);
        if (i < 3) {
            Length1LocX = 40;
            Length1LocY += 100;
        } else if (i == 3) {
            Length1LocX = 150;
            Length1LocY = 150;
        } else if (i > 3) {
            Length1LocY += 100;
            }
        Length2[i].setLocation(Length2LocX, Length2LocY);
        Length2[i].setSize(90, 50);
        add(Length2[i]);
        if (i < 3) {
            Length2LocX = 330;
            Length2LocY += 100;
        } else if (i == 3) {
            Length2LocX = 440;
            Length2LocY = 150;
        } else if (i > 3) {
            Length2LocY += 100;
            }
    } 
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600,600);
    setLocation(400,200);
    setVisible(true);
}
private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("bruhhh");
        if (event.getSource() == amountFrom) {
            System.out.println("works");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
            if (event.getSource() == Length1[i]) {
                from = event.getActionCommand();
            }
            if (event.getSource() == Length2[i]) {
                CTo = event.getActionCommand();
            }
        }

        Step2();
    }
}
}
```

In the middle of my Gui constructor, the "amountFrom" TextField is created, and then I add an actionListener. Then, at the bottom inside of the ActionHandler class I Look for it's event. However, when I Run the program (click on 'Length') and then change the amount From the text Field and press enter, I do not get a console print (It is suppose to print "works" to the console when the textField action occurs).
All of the other Jbutton actionlisteners work but this textfield actionListener won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you add the ActionListener to your JTextField.

```
amountFrom = new JTextField("amount", 20);
amountFrom.addActionListener(handler);
```

But in your method `Step2()` you create a new instance of a JTextField and don't add a listener to it.

```
amountFrom = new JTextField("amount", 20);
amountFrom.setLocation(40,100);
amountFrom.setSize(200,30);
add(amountFrom);
```

Note:
Please have a look at Layout Managers and consider using them. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Awesome, Thanks alot! and yes i'll have to look into layout managers again. I never used it initially because I didn't know if their was one with a column style layout like I have currently. (Plus if i wanted to add another random button such as a back button in the corner I wasn't sure if it would allow me to do that).